# Can I serve a already compressed file over Azure CDN Verizon Premium tier?

Tags: azure, compression, azure-cdn

I have a JS file which has a uncompressed size of 5 MB. Compressed, it is 1-2 MB. According to the Azure docs, Verizon Premium does not support compressing files larger than 1 MB.

Can I send it compressed from the origin server, with the respective headers to be passed on? Or does the file need to be uncompressed from the origin? I think it's the former, but just want to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

If the origin has resource compressed then it will also be compressed on the CDN:
enable compression on your origin server. In this case, **Azure CDN passes along the compressed files and delivers them to clients that request them**.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-improve-performance
provided it wasn't previously cached (assuming not purged or TTL not expire)